# Geokit Gem :Uninitialized Constant

Tags: geokit

so I just want to extract the longitude/latitude coordinates from a regular address(string).  I went to geokit gem documentation and did precisely what was documented, yet I keep getting this error: "NameError: uninitialized constant Geokit::Geocoders::OpenSSL"

I added "geokit" to the gemfile and this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'geokit'




def get_coordinates
  @a = Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode '140 Market St, San Francisco, CA'
  @a.ll
end
```

I've also tried adding this before, but to no avail.
     Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.api_key = api_key

I just want coordinates, if this isn't a viable solution, can someone recommend another geocoder.  I tried the railscasts but couldn't get that to work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'm the maintainer of geokit. We have tests running on ruby 1.8 - 2.1. I'm wondering if somehow you didn't have OpenSSL when ruby was compiled or ruby wasn't compiled with openssl.

Can you assist me by telling me the output of 2 commands:

openssl version

and

ruby -ropenssl -e "require 'openssl'; OpenSSL"
It would also help to know your Operating System and ruby version so I can ensure I'm giving you the right debugging commands, etc.

Comment: I had to explicitly `require 'openssl'` (tested on ruby 2.0.0) to make this error go away (like @Anastasia answered BTW).

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP. I'm on a Mac, running Mavericks, and am using Ruby 2.1. When I run these commands in irb, geokit works provided I require openssl first. However, inside my Padrino app I get the same error message ("uninitialized constant Geokit") even though I also explicitly require openssl there. Geokit is in my Gemfile, has been installed, and also appears under "External Libraries" in my Padrino app.  openssl version yields: "OpenSSL 0.9.8zc 15 Oct 201." When I run the ruby command I get no response, just back to the prompt.

Comment: Okay, my mistake. Normally foreman (the heroku padrino daemon) will pick up a change without needing a restart, but in this case not. It does work after a restart, though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add
`require 'openssl'`
before 
`require 'geokit'`.

Geokit does not automatically include the required OpenSSL gem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @YanSklyarenko what do you mean? This is the solution to the problem, adding the suggested line makes my script run.

Comment: @nathanvda, it might be a solution (although the author hasn't accepted the answer yet), but some more explanation can be helpful.

Comment: The answer was extremely clear to me. The error received is complaining about a missing (standard) library, which Anastasia rightly answers should be included explicitly. There is nothing more to explain. A lot of low-score users do not know how to use the site at all, so I am guessing that is why OP had not accepted the answer. Or he has moved on to something else. This answer was an answer to me, so imho your comment's claim is just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an old Rails app running on an old Ubuntu Lucid. I installed an old version of the geokit gem (1.5.0) and it worked.